# Why does div:hover flicker when overlaying an image?

Tags: html, css, hover

There are many tutorials on how to stop this from happening, but none that I have tried have worked so far. I would appreciate if someone could actually *explain* why the flickering happens so maybe I can find a more suitable / easier solution.

Here is my code:

```css
#Logo {
  content: url('logoWhite.png');
  margin: auto;
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#Logo:hover {
  content: url('logoPink.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="Logo"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by flickering? for me it works fine

Comment: `content` is meant to be used on a pseudo-element. SInce you're using it wrong...it's not surprising you are having issues.

Comment: Works well..see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cm9cdg31/)